# Why is my ListView black?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have this code for my ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="16dip" />
```

and I have the theme "Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" in my Activity. I tried changing the style of the ListView to the same thing, but I am not getting the right colors. In the layout editor in Eclipse it shows this:

[image]

but on my phone I am getting this:

[image: getting]

If I applied a theme to the activity, why won't it change colors?

Answer (score 0):

just an idea that solved a similar problem i had a while ago:

have you applied a theme or style to the ListItems, or just to the ListView?

If that is the Problem, you can find a detailed description of how to do it here:

http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

(I would ask in a comment, but i may not do so yet^^)